# Extract script body or script src for internal and external JS scripts respectively

Tags: go

I have written a function `func getScriptsFromUrl` that accepts a URL and creates two files with script body and script src for internal and external JS scripts respectively.

But since I am totally new to Golang, I doubt if the code is of a high quality, so will highly appreciate if you

- examined my code for compatibility with common Golang standards
- Checked if the used business logic is appropriate
- Provided my with any piece of advice, etc.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func checkError(err error, errorMsg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%s: %s\n", errorMsg, err)
        return
    }
}

func getScriptsFromUrl(url string) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    checkError(err,"Failed to access the provided URL")
    defer res.Body.Close()

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(res.Body)
    checkError(err,"Error loading HTTP response body")

        extScriptsFile, err := os.OpenFile("external_scripts.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 02)
    intScriptsFile, err := os.OpenFile("internal_scripts.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 02)
    defer extScriptsFile.Close()
    defer intScriptsFile.Close()

    scripts := doc.Find("script")
    for i := range scripts.Nodes {
        script := scripts.Eq(i)
        href, srcExists := script.Attr("src")
        if srcExists {
            extScriptsFile.WriteString(href + "\n")
        } else {
            source, err := script.Html()
            checkError(err,"Error getting the script's content")
            intScriptsFile.WriteString(source + "\n")
        }
    }
}

func main(){
    getScriptsFromUrl("https://www.your-site.com")
}
```